# Small English phrase into Latin Tattoo

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

The phrase I want to translate is *"I am my own"* into Latin.
The translations I have seen are different so I'm hoping someone understands the context and can help. It's meant to be a spiritual introspect of belonging to myself but also understanding I am responsible for everything I do and how I effect people.

Comment: There are a lot of words that do what you want. I recommend picking some synonyms in English (rule, govern, direct, control) and plugging them into a dictionary. My favorite one is http://archives.nd.edu/words.html but please feel free to check out this list of dictionaries https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/867/which-online-latin-dictionaries-should-i-use-and-why. Doing this will let you choose the nuances that suit you best.

Comment: That's a really great idea, I saw adpertineo meaning belong to or appertain to, so would I be able to use that in a more specific way? How would I word "I belong to myself" @Nickimite

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest possible version:

*Meus sum. / Mea sum*.

-- depending on whether "I" is male or female.

Comment: Thank you so much! <3

Comment: Is there a reason to prefer this most simple rendering? Or should we try to use more powerful language, like rego, gero, conduco, et cetera?

Comment: @Nickimite That's up to the OP of course, but I'd say it's closer in meaning to the requested phrase than would be something like *Me rego* "I rule myself".

Comment: I appreciate you guys taking the time to help me out this means so much to me! The original saying is meant to have ownership of the good and bad outcomes of my actions, overall I am responsible for my happiness and consequences. The "I rule myself" seems to be similar to what I'm trying to get at but I'm not sure if it's exactly what I'd like. @Nickimite